# uploading binary file to server

Tags: php, image, ubuntu, upload

I'm converting an image to a binary file in IOS, which works just fine. This will be handled by my php script which is suppose to upload this image to my ubuntu server. The problem is i keep getting file=unsuccessful. i've tried different directory paths, but cant seem to solve this issue.

This $directory will return this: /var/www/User/core/ios/

```
<?
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/User/core/ios/';

    $file = basename($_FILES['userfle']['upload']);
    $uploadfile = $directory . $file;
    var_dump($_FILES);
    $randomPhotoID = md5(rand() * time());
    echo 'file='.$file;

echo $file;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfle']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
       echo 'successful';

    }
    else
    {
    echo 'unsuccessful';

}
}
else
{
    echo('Empty post data');
}
?>
```

Comment: have you checked the Permission

Comment: How do i check that? and if thats the case of the problem, how can i get the permission?

Comment: Okay i've checked the file permission is 755

Comment: try copy_uploaded_file instead of move_uploaded_file

Comment: have you tried the copy_uploaded_file? I'm pretty sure this is related to a permission issue.

Comment: Have tried it. This does give me an error 500

Comment: First enable detailed errors by putting this line at absolute top of your script file. error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Answer (score 0):

Check the error file of your php(you can make sure if you enabled the error log in php.ini),
if you don't have the permission or for some other reasons it can't move the file ,there will be a record in that file.
Some time you can try the command `setenforce 0` if you confirm you(I means the user of apache) have the permission to move the file but it not work.
By the way if the file you want to move is not upload by post, there is no error log and the move function will return false.

Comment: I've downloaded my php.ini file. What am i suppose to look for?

Comment: default and production is enabled, but default is not.

Comment: I think you can find a option to turn on the errorlog of you php.(error_log = xxx is the log file position.And you can check out the log file weather it is appended a error record when you run this script.)

Comment: Can you see any error log in the log file when the function called?( you can run tail -f LOG_PATH and run the script, check out if any new content generated).

Comment: error_log is On. I've checked php5-fpm.log in the server there is no error records.